# array_accum in postgresql is giving error

Tags: postgresql

my query is :

```
select d.id,array_to_string(array_accum('name',',')) as name from (select * from temp1 a left join temp3 c on a.id=c.leftid left join temp2 b on b.id=c.rightid) d group by d.id;
```

But it gives me following error :

```
ERROR:  function array_accum(unknown, unknown) does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a expert. Only I checked [documentation of array_accum](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/xaggr.html) and I don't see two parameters in this aggregate function. Maybe this is a problem. Please check it!

Answer (score 1):

The function you're trying to use is an example function to illustrate how to create an user-defined aggregate function:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xaggr.html

It is *not* defined unless you created it in the first place.

Also note, per the docs, that:

> Note: the built-in aggregate `array_agg` provides similar functionality, with better performance than this definition would have.